# Server 2016 standard RDS CAL

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, cal

I wonder if any of you know if there are separate OEM and OLP RDS CALs for server 2016?

Our distributor said that we will be able to use the OLP CALs on an OEM version of 2016 standard. Is this correct?

We got the following product codes quoted, but cannot really tell the difference besides 2 being USER and 2 being Device CALs:

6VC-03222

6VC-03224

6VC-01152

6VC-01149

Comment: Two of those license SKUs include Software Assurance, and two do not. The one you should buy entirely depends on whether you have Software Assurance on the rest of your licenses for RDS.